# PHP loop and removing a character from the loop

Tags: php, loops, echo, factorial

Im doing a factorial loop test for college but I cannot figure this bit out. I want to do the factorial calculation and echo it but also to remove a bit of the calculation.
 So i want it to show:
Factorial of 5 is 120
5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 = 120

But what i get is: 
Factorial of 5 is 120
5 x 4 x 3 x 2 x 1 **x** = 120

This is the code I have so far Within php brackets

```
$i = $num;
do
  {
      echo strrev(" x $i ");
    $i--;
  } while($i > 0);
  echo (" = $factorial");
```

Comment: Does it need to be a literal loop, or can you use functional programming? https://3v4l.org/C41QA  Why are you bothering with `strrev()`?

Comment: Where is factorial declared? Or are you building this in the loop.

Answer (score 2):

You could increase your `while()` condition by one and add another `echo` after the loop ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/C1pVb)), but I don't recommend it.

`do-while()` looping is not appropriate for your scenario if it is possible that `$i = 1`. You should use a pre-test loop.  I am also using the combined "multiplication-assignment" operator to increase the end product.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/X6ZWu))

```
for ($i = 5, $product = 1; $i > 1; --$i) {
    echo $i . ' x ';
    $product *= $i;
}
echo $i . ' = ' . ($product * $i);
```

In a professional application, I'd probably use functional programming, but you are probably only doing this as an academic exercise.  Regardless, here is one way that that style can look:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/VS8er))

```
$i = 5;
$range = range($i, 1);

printf(
    '%s = %d',
    implode(' x ', $range),
    array_product($range)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

This would do the trick:

```
$i = $num;
$factorial = 1;
$sep = "";
do {
    echo "$sep $i";
    $factorial = $factorial * $i;
    $i--;
    $sep = " x";
  } while($i > 0);
  echo ("  = $factorial");
```

Comment: "This'll do" answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
$i = $num;
$factorial = 1;
while($i > 0);
  {
       echo $i . ' x ';
       //if($i>1) echo strrev(" x $i "); strrev would produce undesired output when $num is 10 or greater as pointed out by @wire
      else echo $i;
      $factorial = $factorial * $i;
      $i--;
  }
  echo (" = $factorial");
```

**Or use `Ternary operator` like :**

```
$i = $num;
$factorial = 1;
while($i > 0){
    echo( $i>1 ? $i . ' x '  : $i);
    $factorial = $factorial * $i;
    $i--;
}
echo (" = $factorial");
```

Conidering the input from @mickmackusa, I have modified my answer to fir the purpose.

Comment: "Try this" answers are low value on Stackoverflow because they do very little to educate/empower thousands of future researchers.

Comment: Why do you endorse the use of `strrev()`?

Comment: `strrev()` will produce wrong result if '$i >= 10`